# Stored vector of strings in table implicitly converting to vector of unsigned char, why?

Tags: multi-index, string

I'm trying to store an object in a multi-index table with one of the members a vector of std::string. When retrieving the data however it comes back as a vector of unsigned char, and I can't do anything with it. Why is this happening and what can I do about it?

Comment: Can  you please share code that you have written?

Answer (score 1):

`When describing a vector in your ABI file, simply append the type with []` in pt 2.3 of documentation
https://developers.eos.io/eosio-home/docs